# Grabar Notas en una fecha seleccionada por un Usuario

Tags: c#

Seleccionar una fecha en un MonthCalendar y grabar una nota en un txt con esa fecha.

*Pantalla Inicial*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Nota*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Formulario Principal*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calendar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static string FechaN;
        public static string FechaE;


        private void monthCalendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            frmDayData Tareas = new frmDayData();
            DateTime datevalue = (Convert.ToDateTime(monthCalendar.SelectionEnd.ToShortDateString()));

            //  DateTime datevalue = monthCalendar.SelectionEnd;
           // int Fecha = Convert.ToInt16(datevalue);
            //int Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(datevalue);
            string[] Nota = new string[31];
          //  monthCalendar.DateSelected;
        }

        private void btnWeek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            frmCalendarWeek One = new frmCalendarWeek();
            One.Show();
        }

        private void btnNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FechaN = monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("dd MM yyyy");
           // FechaN = monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.ToString();
            frmDayData Date = new frmDayData(FechaN);
            frmDayData Tareas = new frmDayData();
            //Tareas.Show();
            Date.Show();
        }

        private void btnEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FechaE = monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("dd MM yyyy");
            Evento Date = new Evento(FechaE);
            Evento Event = new Evento();
            Event.Show();
        }


    }
}
```

*Formulario frmDayData*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace Calendar
{
    public partial class frmDayData : Form
    {
        public frmDayData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void lblDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 Month = new Form1();
            this.Close();
        }

        private  string FechaN = null;

        public frmDayData(string FechaN): this()
        {
            this.FechaN = FechaN;



        }

        private void btnNotaSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //string Fecha = Convert.ToString(FechaN);
            string Fecha = FechaN;
            string Nota = Convert.ToString(txtNota.Text);
            StreamWriter GuardarNota = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Martin Fernandez\Desktop\Calendar\Meses\Nota.txt");
            GuardarNota.WriteLine(Fecha + '|' + Nota);
        }

        private void txtNota_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por mas que lo intento, no veo ninguna pregunta aquí.

Comment: Gracias por comentar.No la genere muy bien , como puedo generar recordatorios de notas, al seleccionar una fecha y presionar el boton de agregar nota, el text que incluya el usuario guardarlo en un archivo txt. ?

Comment: Aquí nos muestras un código. Deberías decirnos que problemas tienes con el, porque la pregunta _como puedo generar recordatorios de notas_ es demasiado amplia. Resumiendo, con que estás teniendo el problema concreto? :)

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion relevante a la pregunta. Tambien por favor deja solo el codigo que importa a tu problema.

Comment: El problema es al intentar guardar la fecha y lo ingresado en textBox en el .txt

Comment: ¿Que tal terminar la grabación con un *Flush* para que de salida física a lo grabado y un *Close* para cerrar el fichero?